# Keeping a set number of commits in a shallow clone

Tags: git

I have been looking for a solution to a sliding history window problem for a while now. The problem is as follows:
I have a repository for DNS with many commits, but I only want a set number of commits to exist on the name server. There is no need to have an entire history of the commits on the live machine, so why have it there. I create a shallow clone of a depth of 5 (commits A B C D E) in place. I need to update DNS, and there have been a few commits sense the initial cloning (commits F G H). After the update process has completed, I want the clone to only 5 previous commits (D E F G H). Even after the fetch/merge or pull, the clone will still need the ability to have additional commits fetched/merged or pulled to it.

I know with branching and rebasing you can achieve something like this, as in [Converting git repository to shallow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698759/converting-git-repository-to-shallow) However, I have been unable to make it still compatible with the upstream repository for future merges. To my understanding, it makes a forked branch that is not mergable with the actual branch being used as the "published" version, and therefore, it cannot be used with any future commits. The alternate solution given also does not work, as it causes pruning errors.

This problem is the last component on a shallow clone maintenance script. The basic function of the script will back out any local changes, clean up any un-ignored untracked files, then test to see if there have been updates to the repo (via fetch). If there have been updates to the upstream repo, then it will apply (via pull) them and "move" the commit window forward like in the initial example.

What piece am I missing? Is it even possible without having to delete the existing clone and re-clone?

Comment: "... so why have it there." Out of interest, why _not_ have it there?

Comment: Aren't you able to at least apply patches when you do it the suggested way in the link you provided?

Comment: @Useless I store main repo in gitosis to give access to all of the admin. Plus, there is a space concern.

Comment: @vgoff I could manually apply a patch, but no longer through the GIT mechanism which is the preferred method.

Comment: Not true, this is why the --patch option is there.

Comment: Out of interest, say there have been more that 5 commits since your last update (or more than whatever "shallow" depth you want). Is it ok to lose the "current" state from the history entirely?

Comment: @Useless Yes, it is ok to lose the "current" state from the history entirely. The idea behind keeping the arbitrary depth is more for quick recent history, and to replicate using a sticky "publish" like tag in CVS. Keep the local version current, but make local editing is less feasible.

Comment: @vgoff I have not looked into diff's patch option too deeply. I was trying to keep it within the push-fetch/merge mind set due to dealing with multiple machines using the same "central" origin. I will give it another look.