# How to compact local Git repository

Tags: git

Can I achieve the result of `git clone --depth=1` on a local already cloned repository which has all history while the aim is to keep all the ignored files in place?

I have several Git projects consuming lots of space and I would like to remove all Git history to release some space.

To be more precise:

- I don't want to do any manual work with moving files here and there, deleting repository, recreate, etc.
- I have some configuration files in `assume-unchanged` state which must be kept
- I have many gitignored files which must be left in place

These reasons can make it clear why I don't want to reclone and set up all credentials and stuff on 30 repositories.

Ideally, I'm looking for something I could even run in batch on all projects. If there isn't any such thing, then I'm fine with it of course.

Comment: Related: *[Make Git consume less disk space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398919/)* and *[Reduce Git repository size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116778/reduce-git-repository-size/2116892#2116892)*

Answer (score 10):

> I have several git projects consuming lots of space and I would like to remove all git history to release some space. Thanks

Simply delete the projects and reclone it again with the `git clone --depth --branch ...` to clone a specific branch and the latest commit as you did.

---

#### How to pack your repository:

You have to run gc to do it.

```
# Expire all the unreachable content and pack the repository in the most
# compact way.
git gc --aggressive --prune=now

# Also clear the reflog as well
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
```

---

#### Clean out large files

You should use this tool to clean your repository history: *[An alternative to git-filter-branch](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/)*

It the prefect tool for this kind of task.

> #### BFG Repo-Cleaner
>
> an alternative to git-filter-branch.
>
> The BFG is a simpler, faster alternative to git-filter-branch for cleansing **bad data** out of your Git repository history:
>
> - Removing Crazy Big Files
> - Removing Passwords, Credentials & other Private data

#### Examples (from the official site)

In all these examples, `bfg` is an alias for `java -jar bfg.jar`.

```
# Delete all files named 'id_rsa' or 'id_dsa' :
bfg --delete-files id_{dsa,rsa}  my-repo.git
```

[image]

---

After you have cleaned your repository use [this tool](https://git-lfs.github.com/) to store your large files.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but `git gc --aggressive --prune=now;git reflog expire --expire=now --all` could remove 20MB from `.git` while a `--depth-1` reclone is 45MB smaller

Comment: Of course. since the gc only repack and does not remove any data while clone download only download the latest data of course.

Comment: Just wanted to show you few options which you can choose and learn something new on the way.

Comment: Thanks again, it helps indeed, but I leave it opened because I'm interested if others have better solutions which match more the --depth=1 repo size.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is make a new folder, and clone the repository from the existing folder into it:

```
git clone --depth=1 /path/to/existingFolder /path/to/newFolder
```

Then copy the `.git` directory from `/path/to/newFolder` to `/path/to/existingFolder`, then delete `/path/to/newFolder`.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698759/converting-git-repository-to-shallow), you can edit the `shallow` file directly:

```
git show-ref -s HEAD > .git/shallow
git reflog expire --expire=0
git prune
git prune-packed
```

Comment: Thanks, but too much manual work, also have git-ftp creds and other settings under .git.