# Automate git to keep only the tip of each branch to save space

Tags: git, diskspace

I have a script that generates a lot of commits to a git repository, then periodically pushes all branches. There is no need to keep a big history *on that machine* and it eats up disk space pretty quickly (and my disk space is scarce).

I am currently running a periodic

```
git commit -a (...)
git push --all
git prune
git gc
```

which is not sufficient to keep disk usage low enough on the long run. I am looking for a command to add to this script that would keep only the last few commits from each branch (I only have 2) *on this machine* and then let `git gc` reclaim disk space for me.

Let me clarify: I do not want to rewrite history, just to keep the local repository `.git` directory as small as can be, while keeping the full history on `origin`. Surprisingly I found very little information on that.

**EDIT**: this sounds much like a **shallow repository** (which I never used), but from what I read [here](https://www.perforce.com/blog/git-beyond-basics-using-shallow-clones), a shallow repository means only to skip part of the history at cloning time, not forgetting data after commit/push.

There is a possible workaround, which I will use if nothing better arises:

```
# recreate a shallow clone every commit
git commit -a && git push
rm -rf .git/
git clone --depth=1   # shallow clone
```

Comment: You can use a shallow clone, though I do not know how you would update it to keep truncating N commits behind the tip.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting git repository to shallow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698759/converting-git-repository-to-shallow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing a disk space check as a `cron` job, and whenever the local repository exceeds a threshold (200MB), then "reset" it.

```
git commit -a && git push            # just in case
rm -rf .git/
git clone --depth=1 https://....
```

This solution requires git >= 1.9 since previous versions did not allow push from a repository marked as shallow. 
Also note that very bad things may happen if you are not 100% sure that your working directory is clean.

This is in no way an elegant solution, but that's how I ended up dealing with the problem because I couldn't get git to maintain only the current HEAD and auto-forget the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You could keep on amending to the last commit and force-pushing.

In your script:

```
git commit -a --amend --reuse-message=HEAD
git commit --force push --all
```

This would maintain having only the current number of commits that you currently have.

To be clear though, this is re-writing history, so it's not team-friendly.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand, this will just keep every source modif into one single commit, which will make origin lose history too. I want origin to know everything (just like a regular project), and my "dev machine" to forget after pushing. I will amend the OP to clarify