# Convert git full clone into a shallow clone

Tags: git, shallow-clone

How can a deep clone of a repository be turned into a shallow copy IN PLACE?

I am managing separate installations of our software using git to track any changes to the code in the installation made runtime (untracked & dirty files), but the repository is pretty large (800MB), so having about a few hundreds of copies laying around is not the best idea.

So it would be great if these repositories could be turned into a shallow copy containing only the currently deployed commit, rather than the full tree. 
During an upgrade the repo would be converted back to a deep clone, the specific commit checked out, and then made into a shallow clone of the new commit.

`git fetch --depth=1 --update-shallow` does not shrink the .git directory size, I guess it would fetch any new commits, but it doesn't delete the old data. Adding `--shallow-exclude=HEAD^2` makes git throw an error, not entirely sure how that should work though, I would hazard a guess it's getting conflicting requirements removing HEAD^2, but wanting to check out HEAD, which would depend on HEAD^2 in a deep clone.

```
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting git repository to shallow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698759/converting-git-repository-to-shallow)

Comment: I tried that, and also one of the answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7937916/1726544, but it only reduced the size by about 50MB. I tried deleting all tags before following those steps, but that didn't help either.

Comment: Also did a `git gc --prune`, no difference.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I would expect a shallow clone to be only slightly larger than the working copy itself.

Comment: If I do a "fresh" shallow clone, the repository (.git) is only 17MB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so this was the solution in the end:

```
ORIGIN_URL=$(git remote get-url origin)
COMMIT=$(git rev-parse HEAD)

rm -rf .git
git init .
git remote add origin $ORIGIN_URL
git fetch origin $COMMIT --depth 1
git reset --mixed $COMMIT
```