# Remove completely a local branch

Tags: git, github, branch

I have a repo in a very small environment with a short amount of memory, so every byte counts.
I just finished developing, so I want to remove the dev branch.
Now, my repo is structured like this:

```
(master) A---------E
(dev)     \-B-C-D-/
```

I've already tried `git branch -d dev`, but it ends up deleting dev keeping all the commits, like this:

```
(master) A---------E
          \-B-C-D-/
```

Is there a way to keep only the master branch? Like

```
(master) A---------E
```

Thanks.

Comment: Only with rebasing if you have already performed the merge (rewriting history can be problematic if history is shared). For future merges, use a squash merge (but this comes with its own problem). Are you sure the few extra bytes for the commit headers are a problem?

Comment: Assuming dev points to commit D, `git branch -D dev`. Ahh, you mean remove the fact that E is a merge commit? Yeah, you'll need to rebase.

Comment: I'll check for the squash merge, thanks. The extra bytes per se, aren't a real problem, but for many other reasons, I have to use the least amount of disk space...

the ```-D``` doesn't work either

Answer (score 1):

A "branch" is merely a label for a commit. So deleting a branch just frees up some bytes. The commit `E` still points to `D` so this commit will not be deleted by the [git garbage collection](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc). Same for `C` because it is pointed to by `D` and so on.

The suggested method of **rebasing/squash merging** will get rid of these commits. So you will loose `B-C-D` and `E` and they will all be replaced with a new commit `F`.

If you are really short on disk space and don't care about the history (maybe because you have a clone somewhere else), you could **make your repo shallow** This will get rid of all the commits except `E`. There a quite a few ways to achieve this, covered in this question: [Converting git repository to shallow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4698759/10171966)