# `repo init` did not specify `--depth`, causing the historical commits to be cloned. How to delete these historical commits to save space?

Tags: git, android-source, repo

When I used the repo command to synchronize the Android source code, I forgot to add the --depth parameter, which caused all historical submissions to be included in the synchronization. I want to delete these historical submissions to save my disk space. How to do this?

I tried `repo init --depth=1 ..` again, thinking that this would automatically delete these historical commits, but it didn't. I don't want to restart the synchronization, because it will consume a lot of traffic and time. I just want to delete the historical commits. , to save my disk space

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting git repository to shallow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698759/converting-git-repository-to-shallow)