# How can I clean my .git folder? Cleaned up my project directory, but .git is still massive

Tags: git

The ***.git/objects*** in my rails project directory is still massive, after deleting hundreds of Megabytes of accidentally generated garbage.

I have tried `git add -A`, as well as other commands to update the index and remove nonexistent files.  I gather, perhaps incorrectly, that the files with two character names in the directory are blobs.  I have tried rolling back to previous commits, but no luck.

What can I do to clean this directory?

Comment: Related: *[Make Git consume less disk space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398919/)* and *[Reduce Git repository size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116778/reduce-git-repository-size/2116892#2116892)*

Answer (score 180, accepted):

- If you added the files and then removed them, the blobs still exist but are dangling. `git fsck` will list unreachable blobs, and `git prune` will delete them.
- If you added the files, committed them, and then rolled back with `git reset --hard HEAD^`, they’re stuck a little deeper. `git fsck` will not list any dangling commits or blobs, because your branch’s [reflog](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reflog.html) is holding onto them. Here’s one way to ensure that only objects which are in your history proper will remain:

  ```
  git reflog expire --expire=now --all
  git repack -ad  # Remove dangling objects from packfiles
  git prune       # Remove dangling loose objects
  ```
- Another way is also to clone the repository, as that will only carry the objects which are reachable. However, if the dangling objects got packed (and if you performed many operations, git may well have packed automatically), then a local clone will carry the entire packfile:

  ```
  git clone foo bar                 # bad
  git clone --no-hardlinks foo bar  # also bad
  ```

  You must specify a protocol to force git to compute a new pack:

  ```
  git clone file://foo bar  # good
  ```

Comment: Yep, I did commit before noticing the problem.  I have attempted everything but the last command.  When I run this from within my project directory "warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository." I've been reading the documentation, but it's heavy stuff.  How can I point clone to the correct source?

Comment: @user The `file://foo` URL is relative to the current directory, and a `file:///home/me/foo` (three slashes) is absolute.

Comment: thanks! that's cut size in half, but my pack is still ten times the size of the rest of the repository. I've tried pruning..

Comment: @user If lots of commits have large files erroneously, then you might want to use [git-filter-branch](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/git-filter-branch/faq) to pick at them.

Comment: Sorry, with no effect. My dev lead says that the size is now within acceptable but unfavorable range.  If you have the time to keep spoon feeding me that would be excellent, but you've gotten me back on my feet.  Thanks jleedev.

Comment: Very useful answer, and most complete with the `git repack -ad` suggestion.

Answer (score 57):

Have you tried the [`git gc`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html) command?

Comment: `git gc --aggressive --prune` works for me. `git gc` does not. Maybe default setting is not enough.

Comment: By default [`--prune`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc#Documentation/git-gc.txt---pruneltdategt) deletes dangling objects that are older than 2 weeks. You can pass `--prune=now`, but than you risk corrupting the repository if another process is writing to the repository concurrently.

Answer (score 21):

Sparkleshare created 13GB of tmp_pack_ files in my git after failing to pull multiple times huge binaries. 'git gc' did not remove those files. The only thing that helped was ...

```
rm -f .git/objects/*/tmp_*
```

rm -f is dangerous! Have a backup. You can test before:

```
find .git -name "tmp_*" -print
```

Not sure if this is still an issue after so many years, but do not use this if you do not know what you are doing, are unsure about the OS or git version (which tells you do not know that this is globbing by the unix shell). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)

Comment: Desperate situations require desperate measures, It worked like a charm! Tks.

Comment: rm is for linux command? what about windows user then @cat?

Comment: What system was it tested on? (Operating system, edition/flavour, incl. versions. Git version.)

Answer (score 9):

If you still have a large repo after pruning and repacking (`gc --aggressive --prune=tomorrow`...) then you can simply go looking for the odd one out:

```
git rev-list --objects --all |
    while read sha1 fname
    do 
        echo -e "$(git cat-file -s $sha1)\t$\t$fname"
    done | sort -n
```

This will give you a sorted list of objects in ascending size. You could use git-filter-branch to remove the culprit from your repo.

See "Removing Objects" in http://progit.org/book/ch9-7.html for guidance

Comment: Just in case anyone else trips over this: there's a typo in the args in parenthesis: should be `--aggressive`. Tried to edit, but it turns out you can't edit such a small typo.

Comment: @hellobenallan thanks for the note, [fixed](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5293344/revisions)

Answer (score 2):

Recursively:

```
find ./ -iname '*.!*' -size 0 -delete
for i in */.git; do ( echo $i; cd $i/..; git gc --aggressive --prune=now --force; ); done
```