# Removing branch with garbage from git

Tags: git

Unfortunately we have no `.gitignore` file yet and some programmers in our team didn't work with git before.

Yesterday branch with IDE temporary files was pushed to repo. They are not on master branch. Now uncomfortable to work with 200+ megabytes repo.

If I remove this problematic branch is it help?

Maybe `git` have some instruments for such situation?

Comment: I believe if you just delete that branch from the remote (and locally), you should be OK.  This assumes that no bad commits with large objects were made to any other active branch which you or your team plans to continue using.  Others may also need to remove the tracking branch.

Comment: As part of fixing this problem, *add a .gitignore file*.

Comment: To delete a branch (**PLEASE UNDERSTAND WHAT THIS DOES BEFORE YOU DO IT!!!**), use `git branch -d BRANCH-NAME` and `git push origin -d BRANCH-NAME`.

Comment: If you have already based other branches on these changes, or merged them into master and people have branches based on that, you might need to rewrite the history using `git filter-branch`, google for instructions on how to do this.

Comment: [This answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5277575/151344) has some instructions about what you can do to remove the dangling objects, after having deleted the branch.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, put all the file names in `.gitignore`. If the file names have the same extension, you can simply put `*.extension` or if they are in the same folder you can put `folder/`. After that, use `git rm --cached filename.txt` where `filename` is the name or names of all the files that you want to remove from the repository.

Comment: Changes already in remote repo and my worst fears that this already cloned by other developers.

Comment: This does not remove the files from the repository, though.

Comment: This does not remove the files from the file system, but stops git from tracking them. But you need these files to work on your project using the IDE so they need to be in the file system, just not being tracked by git. You can do a `git add -A` after it to commit the changes

Comment: @StepanLoginov Once you do the above changes, commit them and push them to the remote branch, it'll remove the files from the remote repo branch as well

Comment: `git rm` won't remove the files from the history. The repository will still be 200+ MB bigger. You need something like `git filter-branch` to fix that as well, unless you can just remove the commits altogether by hard-reset or deleting a branch.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen - yeah it won't reduce the size of the repository. It will only prevent future tracking