# git how to remove untracked files from the pack file

Tags: git

I removed a folder\files from my Git repo by running

```
git rm -r --cached Application01
```

to untrack all the files in that folder and reduce the size of the Git repo.

The problem is that the pack file .git/objects/pack/*.pack is still holding the files I removed\untracked.

How can I completely remove all untracked files and lose all their history and make the pack file smaller?

Thanks

Comment: The files still exist in your version history - after all, git is a version control system - so if you really want to reduce the size of your repo you need to rewrite history.

Answer (score 1):

try to run this command

```
git gc
```

this will run git garbage collector to clean up unnecessary files and optimise your local repository

Comment: you can try with the option --aggressive as well. See documentation below    https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc

Comment: I tried `git gc --prune=now --aggressive`, but that didn't remove the files.

Comment: I think the problem has been solved here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050265/remove-large-pack-file-created-by-git