# Large Amount of .git/objects

Tags: git, github, localhost, bitbucket, magento-1.9

I am handling a project in Magento, and my project is in bit-bucket repository.
I have a large amount of unused files in my .git/object folder.

```
du -a -h myproject/.git/objects | sort -n -r | head -n 100
```

It displays like

```
769M    myproject/.git/objects/pack/pack-e8ca98308b512b34aaf887c85e1f1b7414a65e90.pack
760K    myproject/.git/objects/54
737M    myproject/.git/objects/pack/tmp_pack_ba3Zw1
732K    myproject/.git/objects/pack/pack-e6fb69581vb652c624823f24f455248b3cf6805b.pack
```

I don't have any files in my directory now with such large amount. Earlier by mistake one zip was pushed in master branch and now I have removed that zip from git as well as from my local repo.

I want to remove this entry since it increased my git repo as 1.2 GB.

I have done some research about **git -gc** and **git -prune**. Not sure if it affect my vcs history or any commits or else in my repo.

How can I remove this large data entry in .git/object directory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Completely remove file from all Git repository commit history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307828/completely-remove-file-from-all-git-repository-commit-history)

Comment: This problem is already well-covered on Stack Overflow.  You should try something and then ask a question if you get stuck.

Comment: I searched, but nothing was found working for me... I think I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove large .pack file created by git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050265/remove-large-pack-file-created-by-git)