# Large pack file git not solved

Tags: git, github

My question is identical to this one.
[Remove large .pack file created by git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050265/remove-large-pack-file-created-by-git)

I followed all the steps listed here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery and also tried all the steps listed in this [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11277929/5705536). However, the size of the pack file is still large.

Before:

```
count: 0
size: 0
in-pack: 2259
packs: 1
size-pack: 67333
prune-packable: 0
garbage: 0
size-garbage: 0
```

After:

```
count: 0
size: 0
in-pack: 2259
packs: 1
size-pack: 67333
prune-packable: 0
garbage: 0
size-garbage: 0
```

I can still run this command: `git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/pack-xxx.idx | sort -k 3 -n | tail -3` and see the three largest files and their corresponding commits but when I run `git log --oneline --branches -- <large_file_name>`, there are no commits which reference the file, which may be because I rewrote the history of commits. Clearly, I seem to have messed up somewhere along the line.

My question is, how to fix this issue regarding the large .pack file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ... when I run `git log --oneline --branches -- <large_file_name>`, there are no commits which reference the file, which may be because I rewrote the history of commits ...

That's fine (assuming that's your intent).  What you need to do now is make sure no *other* external references reach commits that use the file(s).

Using `--branches` tells `git log` or `git rev-list`<sup>1</sup> to look at all *branch name* references, i.e., everything under `refs/heads/`.  But there may be *tag name* references under `refs/tags/`, so you should check there.  There may even be other references, so you should check all of them.  The easiest way to do that is to use `--all` rather than `--branches`: that looks at all references.

But this also misses the *reflogs.*  Every reference has (at least potentially) a reflog.  To walk the reflogs, use `-g` or `--walk-reflogs`.  Note that you must do this separately.  If there's a reflog entry that references the commit, you can expire it manually; or you can use the brute-force method of just expiring all reflogs wholesale (which is a little dangerous since the reflogs are your main safety net, but you *are* doing all this on a *copy* of the original repository, right? :-) ).

Note that when you use `git filter-branch` to "rewrite history", you're really *copying* all of history to a new history.  As such, you can temporarily increase the repository size up to about double, depending on what you do in your filters.  Removing old reflogs and removing the saved original references under the `refs/original/` namespace, followed by garbage collection, should shrink things back to size.

Note also that if a pack file has a corresponding `.keep` file, Git won't throw out the kept pack even after building a new pack that covers everything.  Any `.keep` files were created manually and must be removed manually if and when that's appropriate.

---

<sup>1</sup>These two commands, `git log` and `git rev-list`, are actually pretty much just one command, built from one source file, [`builtin/log.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/log.c).  They have slightly different entry points, that set up some different default options, and `git log` will start from `HEAD` if you don't name any other starting points, while `git rev-list` demands some starting points.

Comment: There's also a plain `--reflog` option to add every reflog entry as if given on the command line, same as `--branches` adds every branch tip.

Comment: @torek and @jthill - Thanks a lot for all the information. I finally managed to shrink my repository size. This [checklist] (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_checklist_for_shrinking_a_repository) helped me figure it out in addition to your comments. To be more specific, I followed the these commands:`git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/original/ | xargs -n 1 git update-ref -d`, `git reflog expire --expire=now --all` and finally `git gc --aggressive --prune=now`

Comment: @jthill: huh, this flag has been in since Git 1.5.0, but wasn't documented until Git 2.2.0 (and I was not aware of it).