# Pack file remove it in git

Tags: git, github, gitlab

In one of my server i've a big file like 2G ( pack )in Git.
I'read some documentation but i didn't find any information about if you remove it  without damage my git repository .

Do you have any idea about that ?

regards

Comment: Please clarify your question by adding context, What is that file and where is it located in relation to your git repo?

Comment: What kind of damage are you expecting on your repository ? I've never heard of a damaged repository caused by the removal of some file. I mean, that is one of the main purposes of a git repository (add/edit/remove files), so I don't really understand what you're afraid of.

Answer (score 6):

If you mean pack files in [`.git/objects/pack/`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Packfiles) then yes there will be damage. These files are essential parts of the [git object database](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects). Please do not mess with files in `.git/objects/`.

If the pack files are too large you need to edit history to remove large files and repack. See these questions and answers: [Remove large .pack file created by git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11050265/7976758), [Large pack file git not solved](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48000629/7976758).