# How to shrink git pack file

Tags: git

I have git repo with android app and It looks like one of developers didn't gitignore correctly so .apk files were committed and repo became huge (repo is ~300Mb, app size is ~30Mb).

I deleted some garbage:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch ./app/release/app-release.apk' --tag-name-filter cat -- --all

git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch ./app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk' --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Repo size became smaller, it's 200Mb now,
but when I'm searching for big commits:

```
git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/pack-*.idx | sort -k 3 -n | tail -20
```

I still see commits which contain .apk files, but I can't even checkout those commits:
[image]

So the question is how can I shrink that pack file?

Comment: Complete side-question, if that screenshot is from macOS terminal, how did you get that specific prompt there? I've been trying to get something better than the just basic branch information and would really love to have that branch icon and so on as well.

Comment: If you dont need that file, I assume you do not need the .apk file, why not delete it entirely?

Comment: Try `git repack -A` followed by `git gc --aggressive --prune`, followed by another `git repack -A`, see if that helps.

Comment: The .apk file is not a commit, and not even a tree, it's just a file (blob). You need to find, or at least just get rid of, the commit(s) that contain that blob, and what name(s) make those commits reachable. If they're retained by reflogs or `refs/original/` references, they won't be garbage collected until that's no longer the case.

Comment: Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen after git repack -A, git gc --aggressive --prune, git repack -A size has been reduced from 213Mb to 198Mb so it's still huge

Comment: @Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen you could use this gude to make your terminal nice - https://gist.github.com/kevin-smets/8568070

Comment: @torek so how could I remove those blobs from all commits?

Comment: You can't *remove* them from commits. You can *copy* existing commits to new, different commits that are pretty similar to the originals, but lack the large blobs. That's what your `git filter-branch` commands do. Then you stop *using* the old commits—that's the part you haven't achieved, yet: *something* is still using the old commits. `git gc` can't remove them until *nothing* is using them. Find what's using them (reflogs and/or `refs/original/` references for instance) and remove those references, provided you're sure the to-be-kept data are safely copied.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove large .pack file created by git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050265/remove-large-pack-file-created-by-git)

Comment: @kagarlickij Thanks! Will try it out tonight!

Comment: probably you should force expiration as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050265/remove-large-pack-file-created-by-git#comment80426899_11277929). If that fails you need to find somehow which commits still refer to the blob, and are there references which prevent the commits from beibg collected

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I had the same issue (with [SecLists](https://github.com/danielmiessler/SecLists)). Results (.git dir size, MB): after `repack`: 1017; after `gc`: 446; after 2nd `repack`: 892. For some reason, the 2nd `repack` created a copy of a pack object (446  MB) that's `diff`-identical . Any ideas?

Comment: Ran `git repack -Ad` and it's back to 446.