# error: pack-objects died of signal 9517 when trying to re-write history

Tags: git, git-gc, git-history

A git repository that I'm interacting with has a huge package file (1.7Gb!) so I've tried to follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11277929). I was able to use `git filter-branch`, but when I run `git gc --aggressive --prune=now` I get:

```
$ git gc --aggressive --prune=now     

Counting objects: 119622, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
error: pack-objects died of signal 9517)   
error: failed to run repack
```

I tried to lower the threads to 2 and 1 already using `git config --global pack.threads "2"` but it didn't help.

Thanks!

Comment: Try to [increase memory for packing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4829883/7976758).

Comment: This is actually *died of signal 9*.  The `517)` is left over from earlier text, that `git pack-objects` was planning to overwrite when something killed `git pack-objects`, probably the OOM killer.

Comment: Sorry of the late response but you @torek saved the day.