# Compact repository by removing old commits

Tags: git

Is there a way to reduce repository size by removing local copy of data about old commits?

Similar to how `git clone --depth 5` produces a small local clone with only recent commit data.

The repository contains gigabytes of game assets which were overwritten multiple times in past.

I don't want to just purge the past history; I want the history to remain consistent with the remote, but I don't want old commits to be locally stored and available.

Comment: When you say "old commits", I'm guessing you don't mean dangling commits that are no longer reachable from a branch pointer, just really old commits in your history that you're unlikely to ever visit again in the near future, would that be correct?

Comment: @TheShadow right, I'll update the question

Comment: @Hardex: to answer your updated question: it is NOT possible to keep only most recent commits in history and have fully usable repository. shallow copy is not fully usable - it cannot be committed into.

Comment: @mvp thank you. Would you please add this info to your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @Hardex: added this comment into my answer per your request.

Comment: Related: *[Make Git consume less disk space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398919/)* and *[Reduce Git repository size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116778/reduce-git-repository-size/2116892#2116892)*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is ***not*** possible to keep only most recent commits in history and have **fully usable** repository. Shallow copy is ***not*** fully usable because it cannot be committed into.

In other words, because of the way git keeps data in object store, you don't have many options other than rewriting history from scratch.

Probably easiest approach is to make a copy of all current game asset files somewhere outside of git repository, then use `git filter-branch` as [described here](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data) to remove your assets from history, like it never existed. Finally, copy assets back into their rightful place and commit them once again. This will rewrite your history in a way that game assets only appear in most recent commit.

However, it will still not reclaim disk space though until you do:

```
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now
```

Answer (score 3):

`git gc --prune=<date>` should do what you want. Take a look into documentation: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html

**Update1:** I suggest you to read this blog post about `git gc` as well: http://gitfu.wordpress.com/2008/04/02/git-gc-cleaning-up-after-yourself/

**Update2:** @mvp is right, after a deep research `git gc` will only remove untracked objects. In order to remove objects one of the solution is to use `git filter-branch`. I suggest you to read this topic about [removing objects](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery#Removing-Objects) and the [git filter-branch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) documentation. Thanks for the heads up @mvp.

Comment: you are totally wrong. `git gc --prune` will NOT do what OP wants

Comment: you are right @mvp, I already updated my answer. Tks for the heads up.

Comment: @danielcsgomes for what it's worth, if the original poster **was** interested in removing dangling commits, `git gc` would indeed have been the right tool to use.