# What is the .git folder?

Tags: git

What is the folder called *.git*?

It's created in a repository. What is contained within it and why is it created?

Comment: Not sure about "too broad". It seems to me that this question is pretty specific, even if it is poorly researched.

Comment: (Almost) everything is explained in the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Plumbing-and-Porcelain).

Comment: I was actually wondering what it's called, if it has a name other than "dot git folder". Is the .git directory the repository or is the directory it's in the repository?

Comment: @hippietrail, that seems like a good separate question itself.

Comment: Related: *[Make Git consume less disk space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398919/)* and *[Reduce Git repository size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116778/reduce-git-repository-size/2116892#2116892)*

Answer (score 52):

Folder *.git* is initialized by `git init`.

*.git* contains all information required for version control. If you want to clone your repository, copying *.git* is enough.

Four sub-directories:

- *hooks/* : example scripts
- *info/* : `exclude` file for ignored patterns
- *objects/* : all "objects"
- *refs/* : pointers to commit objects

Four files:

- HEAD : the current branch
- config : configuration options
- description
- index : staging area

Here "object" includes:

- blobs (files)
- trees (directories)
- commits (reference to a tree, parent commit, etc.)

Answer (score 27):

The *.git* folder contains all the information that is necessary for your project in version control and all the information about commits, remote repository address, etc. All of them are present in this folder. It also contains a log that stores your commit history so that you can roll back to history.

For more information, you can check the [official website of Git](https://git-scm.com/).

Answer (score 13):

This explanation should help beginners to understand the *.git* folder.

The *.git* folder is a bit like a magic hat into which you put your current magic show.

When you create a new Git repository (`git init`), everything you organise into a show format is put inside this magic hat and can be 'pulled out' whenever, wherever you want.

After pulling everything out, you can throw everything away when you are finished with the show (i.e., all your files except the `.git` folder), and you can always pull out exactly the same show at a later date. (As each new show is simply a clone of what is inside the hat.)

If you send someone *just* the `.git` folder, they can always pull out your project files into the same structure (show format) as you put them in.

`git add` tells the *.git* folder what is able to be pulled out, e.g., a rabbit wearing a tuxedo and holding a cane (or a single file or whole menu bar on your website).

`git rm` tells the *.git* folder to stop allowing something to be pulled out of the hat, e.g., imagine if you no longer wanted the rabbit to be part of your magic show. (It is important to note that you can still recover a previous version of your show, which would include the rabbit (your 1999 version of your blog with [Comic Sans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comic_Sans)), if you really wanted, but your current show would not include the rabbit if you used `git rm`).

Answer (score 4):

This is the "thing" which makes your project a Git repository.
The *.git* folder is the directory which is created when you do `git init` (in case of a new project) or you do `git clone` (in case of pulling a project from somewhere else).  Without *.git*, your project is a local project and not a Git project, that means you cannot perform any git operations.

Git stores the metadata and object database for the project in this directory like:

1. Remote information (to which remote server your project is connected)
2. History of all local commits
3. Branch information (on which branch is your current project state (HEAD) pointing to)
4. All logs of all local commits you have ever made (including revert changes)

To know more, check the official documentation from Git on their homepage:
*[2.1 Git Basics - Getting a Git Repository](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository)*

Answer (score 3):

Basically, it means your directory is handled by Git (Git repository). If you move it somewhere else (or delete it), you'll face something like

> fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

every time you use 'git *' command there.

You can move the **.git** directory somewhere else using:

```
git --git-dir=/myproject_path/myproject.git log --oneline
```

Or:

```
export GIT_DIR=/myproject_path/myproject.git
```

But I don't recommend doing it.
Pay attention that it is only one folder, unlike [SVN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Subversion).

It holds all relevant information for Git to handle your code, like the position of the *HEAD*, hooks to apply before/after commit/push and some other files.

Maybe most "famous" file inside is the configuration file which holds all your branches information.

I recommend to read [here](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/03/23/whats-inside-your-git-directory.html) more information.

Answer (score 2):

Technically that `.git` directory is **the Git repository itself**. All contents of the repository, including all file versions, tags, branches, etc., are spread across files within this directory.

Things immediately outside `.git` comprise the *working directory*, which is an optional accomodation to make working with your Git repository easier. By default working directory reflects the latest commit of your local repository, but you can switch your working directory tree to different commits within the repository, and modify/create/delete files within the working directory before making a new commit.

Without a working tree you can still have a *bare* Git repository—it consists *only* of the `.git` directory (normally named `<something>.git` in this scenario) and nothing else. It’s not commonly used except on Git servers.

Answer (score 0):

The inner workings of the *.git* folder can be found here, hiding in the last chapter of the **Official Git Documentation**:

*[10.1 Git Internals - Plumbing and Porcelain](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Plumbing-and-Porcelain#ch10-git-internals)*

Comment: That is essentially a link-only answer. We expect more from answers here.