# How to ungit a directory?

Tags: git

I have accidentally put my home folder under git version control. How can I undo this? I am running Ubuntu 16.04.

Interestingly, running

```
$ git status
```

Informs me that the Mozilla Firefox cache has been altered.

[Screenshot of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mou4p.png)

---

Related questions:

- [What is the .git folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29217859/what-is-the-git-folder)
- [What is the alternative for ls command in linux? [duplicate]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/222494)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try removing the `.git` directory and `.gitignore` if exist: `rm -Rf .git .gitignore`

Comment: Entering _ls_ into the terminal didn't show _.git_ or _.gitignore_, but running rm -Rf .git .gitignore solved the problem.

Comment: @salehgeek That is because `ls` doesn't show hidden files by default. you would have better luck with `ls -A` or `ls -a` (the latter also shows the current and top  directories as '.' and '..')

Answer (score 4):

You can just remove the `.git` folder from your homedir.

Answer (score 3):

The shorted command should be

```
rm -Rf .git*
```

---

EDIT:

You must remove only `.git` folder. Your home's `.gitignore` file is used by git to automatically ignore files. For example, ... instead of put .idea (an editor dot file) in all your project, you can just add it once in your global gitignore.

Tecnically

```
rm -rf .git*
```

delete also this .gitignore file.

Comment: Don't do it — the command will remove global .gitconfig if you have it! Just do `rm -rf .git`.

Comment: Lol. Are you sure?

Comment: And tell me, ... if you are inside the project's folder, how can you be also in the root folder where the global .gitignore file is present?

Comment: .git* is an alias for ".git .gitignore"

Comment: The original poster asked about his home folder — and this is exactly where global .gitignore is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145749/discussion-between-phd-and-sensorario).