# What happen if I ignore the .pack files under ./.git/objects/pack/ during push?

Tags: git, github

I am using Enterprise GitHub and it has a threshold for file size.

If I ignore the file `./.git/objects/pack/pack-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.pack` when pushing the folder to GitHub, what will be the consequence?

Comment: Was one of your push actually rejected by the server, with a message clearly indicating that this pack file was the cause of rejection ?

Comment: The pack file (format of file use by git to store and exchange commits) is just the symptom of the real problem that you have committed a too big file. You have to remove it from the history if you want to be able to push to github (or use git-lfs).

Comment: @LeGEC, yes, because the .pack file is too large and because Enterprise GitHub has file size restriction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The threshold applies to versioned files, before compression.

The `.pack` files stored under `.git/` are internal storage files, and are not versioned.

---

[Github's doc page about large files](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.17/user/managing-large-files/conditions-for-large-files) implicitly talks about versioned files, you do not have to look at .pack files hidden under `.git/`.

First, have a look at the large files in your code : check if you haven't committed a file which happens to be larger than your repo's size limit.

You can do this with the following command (run it in `git bash` if you are running Windows) :

```
git ls-tree -r --long HEAD | sort --key 4 --numeric-sort --reverse | less
```

Second : look for large files in all of your repo's history. See for example [this gist in github](https://gist.github.com/magnetikonline/dd5837d597722c9c2d5dfa16d8efe5b9)

Answer (score 0):

`.git` is the working directory for git. You should not add it in your repository (and obviously not push it).

You can learn more there : [What is the .git folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29217859/what-is-the-git-folder)

Comment: In fact, you *can't* add it to your repository (there were at one time various bugs that let you do that on some systems, but those were bugs and should all be fixed now).