# Cloud Shell git repository not found after repo move

Tags: git, github, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

After creating a new organisation on GitHub and moving the repo from the old organisation to the new one I get the error message: **"fatal: repository 'https://github.com/newOrganisation/repo.git/' not found"** when doing `git push` within the Cloud Shell.

Within Cloud Shell I never have to input a personal access token to be able to do `git push`, on my local machine I do have to input it. Therefore I assume my git credentials are somehow stored within Cloud Shell and need to be updated, I just do not know how. Any help would be appreciated.

What I have tried out so far:

1. Cloned the repo to my local machine and pushed a commit --> everything worked fine
2. Compared `git config -l` on both machines, user.email and remote.origin.url were the same

Comment: Note that GitHub will claim that a private repository does not exist (rather than cannot be accessed) if you have not provided proper credentials. So this looks like a credential-providing issue. (That's what you concluded as well.)

Answer (score 1):

Although you can workaround with:

```
git remote remove origin 
git remote add origin https://[personal-access-token]@github.com/username/repo_name.git
```

Cloud Shell is just a Debian-based Linux distribution which [includes Git pre-installed](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/how-cloud-shell-works#tools).

As it is told in this [issue tracker report](https://issuetracker.google.com/228526856), *we don't do anything special with git credentials in Cloud Shell*. As long as the credentials are in the user's home directory, **they will be persisted across sessions.** Otherwise, Cloud Shell works the same as any other Linux VM, so it's possible the user messed up their global or repo git configuration somewhere.

As you can [read here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage), **the  git credentials can be stored in** `~/.git-credentials` but also in another file like `~/.my-credentials`. The “store” mode saves the credentials to a plain-text file on disk, and **they never expire**. This means that until you change your password for the Git host, you won’t ever have to type in your credentials again. **The downside of this approach is that your passwords are stored in cleartext in a plain file in your home directory.**

You can also find your credentials as described [here](https://www.shellhacks.com/git-config-username-password-store-credentials/#:%7E:text=The%20username%20and%20password%20will,of%20the%20remote%20repository%20URL.) in `.git/config` file. In Cloud Shell, you can find it in `./cloudshell_open/python-storage/.git` from your `$HOME` directory. `config` is the local configuration file, as you can read in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56026788/17544309).

As established [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/2.6.7#_configuration_file), the Git configuration file contains a number of variables that affect the Git commands' behavior. The `.git/config` file in each repository is used to store the configuration for that repository, and `$HOME/.gitconfig` is used to store a per-user configuration as fallback values for the `.git/config` file. The file `/etc/gitconfig` can be used to store a system-wide default configuration.

With this respect, there’s no particular configuration related to Cloud Shell.

In other case, when [authenticating with git](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/version-control#authenticating_with_git), **if you're working with [Cloud Source Repositories](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs), Cloud Shell handles authentication for you automatically.** If that’s your case, you could [view your repository settings](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/viewing-settings#view_repository_settings) and display your repository location. This could be outdated with the previous one before you move it to the new organization.

Probably you also need to [toggle between your repositories](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/version-control#toggling_between_multiple_repositories) to connect to the one that is in your new organization. This updates your Source Control: Git panel with the context of your chosen repository.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not working with Cloud Source Repositories, it is GitHub.

Comment: Have you [check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37813568/17544309) to see if any solution works for you?

You could try `git push <repository URL>` or other git push related options as described in [this doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) to update your push destination.

This doc also establishes that when the command line does not specify where to push with the <repository> argument, `branch.*.remote` configuration for the current branch is consulted to determine where to push. If the configuration is missing, it defaults to origin.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that this is working: ```git remote remove origin``` and ```git remote add origin https://[personal-access-token]@github.com/username/repo_name.git``` Nevertheless it seems to be another way of pushing this repo than for my other repos. It would be great if I understand how the credentials are stored withing Cloud Shell, becasue then I could use the same method for all repos/organisations.

Comment: was this answer useful?

Comment: Yes it was useful, I have managed to push the repo. Do you also know how the credentials are stored within Cloud Shell, so I can solve the underlying issue?

Comment: I updated my answer. Does the update solve your underlying issue related to how the credentials are stored within Cloud Shell?

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately there is no ```~/.git-credentials``` and also no custom file. I also double checked via ```git config --global -l``` there is no path to a custom file stored, only user.email and user.name are stored.

Comment: I wrote a new update to my answer. Please, let me know if that solves the underlying issue.

Comment: Thank you. The right repo seems to be connected. But I am using VS Code's "Code Server" and not the default Cloud Shell editor Theia. Can it be that "Code Server" somehow stores the credentials?

Comment: Because Cloud Shell is not the same as VS Code's Code Server, please, as a best practice in Stackoverflow, create a new post for your question related to VS Code's "Code Server". The VS Code Server is a component of the Remote Development extensions and is managed by a VS Code client. Meanwhile [this article](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/faq) may help you.