# How do I find the .git file in github?

Tags: github

All I have been using for my project is github. I don't know how to use git. For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to include the .git file when I download my project as a zip from github. It is important that it is included for my project. How do I make sure this is included?

All I can find in my .zip after downloading it is .gitignore

Comment: The real problem here is *"I don't know how to use git"*. You should have a look at a good tutorial on Git, as using the GitHub interface to manage files in a Git project is really not the right way. Start for instance with: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: you don't.

The `.git` directory is more or less a container for a bunch of metadata and local repository state tracking, which is read and written by the `git` command. Much of the information stored there is specific to each person's local repository or stores data relating to mulitple branches, making it impractical to store that data in the remote repo which is why even when running `git add .git` you won't see the directory staged for commit. THis answer gives a good overview of what is contained in the `.git` directory: [What is the .git folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29217859/what-is-the-git-folder)

When you download a repository as a zip from github, it can't assume that you are looking for a git repository so it doesn't include one. If you have downloaded the zip you can add the `.git` directory with `git init`. This is only so helpful since it isn't hooked up to a remote repo yet. You can add the remote with `git remote add <remote name> <upstream url>`.

However, all of this can be done by simply cloning the repo rather than downloading the zip.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading a zip is the same as using the 'git archive' command really. It's a cleaned version of your app with none of the special metadata that makes it a repository.

If you want it to be a repository you can run git commands against, you CAN download the zip, extract it, git init the directory then set the upstream. However, if you just clone it instead of downloading a zip, your directory will already be a working repository.