# How to compact the '.git' directory in Git

Tags: git, github, initialization

Here is the respective size of directories inside of a [Ruby on Rails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails) application that I have inherited:

```
→ find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -mindepth 1 -exec du -hs {} \;
263M    ./.git
2.0M    ./app
124K    ./config
728K    ./db
4.0K    ./doc
 56K    ./lib
  0B    ./log
232K    ./public
8.0K    ./script
164K    ./spec
560K    ./spreadsheets
 16K    ./test
 64K    ./vendor
```

I made a new repository off an existing repository branch on GitHub and left the old one intact.  **I do not need any history in the new repository** since that particular branch of the old repository became the master for the new repository and that is the only branch in the new repository.

I would like to get the size of folder *.git* to a minimum size to start with since it is an absolute waste in terms of GitHub space, local space, and [Heroku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroku) deployment.

Git init did not work.  I do not know if I can just

```
rm -rf .git
```

and then reinitialize the Git repository and then push it to GitHub remote.

Comment: If you do not need any history then reset the git by removing the `.git` folder and issuing `git init`.

Comment: Related: *[Make Git consume less disk space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398919/)* and *[Reduce Git repository size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116778/reduce-git-repository-size/2116892#2116892)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute the following commands:

```
# remove old content
rm -rf .git

# init new repo
git init

# add all current files (add .gitignore entries if you need to ignore some files)
git add -A .

# commit the current content
git commit - m ".. Message..."

# add the remote url of the github server
git remote add origin <github new url>

# oush your code to github
git push origin master
```

Comment: Thank you both, that is what I did.  Works.

Answer (score 2):

In order to compact the *.git* directory, persist just certain branches, removing old commits.

Please perform the following steps:

1. [Delete the branches you don't need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely)
2. [Amend commits before the one you need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186535/how-to-modify-a-specified-commit-in-git)
3. [Perform garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28720151/git-gc-aggressive-vs-git-repack)