# Why can the size of folder '.git' be smaller than the working directory?

Tags: git

According to my understanding, folder *.git* contains all the `blob` and `commit` objects. So it will always be larger than the files in the working directory.

How can this happen? Is it because the repository contains many small files (less than the block size), and Git will compress them?

What is the more detailed explanation?

Actually, the repository that makes me confused is the CocoaPods [master](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs) repository. This repository is used to store the iOS library specifications. When a new version of a library is released, [a new file](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/tree/master/Specs/0/0/0/CodeQuickKit) is added (no edit of existing ones) to this repository. The new added specification is usually very similar to the previous version, and maybe only the version is changed. This will add at least three objects to the repository, a blob, a tree and a commit.

Using `du -d 1 h`, the size is

> 1.1G  ./Specs
>
> 729M  ./.git

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does git store files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198105/how-does-git-store-files)

Comment: compression, reused-data etc.

Comment: @Mureinik Maybe this questions contain some information, but this one force on this specific case.

Comment: Related: *[Make Git consume less disk space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398919/)* and *[Reduce Git repository size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116778/reduce-git-repository-size/2116892#2116892)*

Answer (score 3):

> So it always is larger than the file in the working directory.

Nope.

In order to understand you need to know how Git stores its data.
Git uses heuristics to find similar parts of your code. In other words, when Git finds identical content (whole file or part of it), it doesn't store it twice, but instead, it stores it once and uses the pointer to point to the first occurrence. This is known as **hunks**.

Whenever you execute `git add`, Git grabs the content, "sets" up the **hunks** and stores them later on inside the pack file. So back to track, when you execute `git add` Git grabs the content, hashes it using [sha1sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sha1sum), hash-object and more, zips it and stores it inside your *.git/objects* folder.

The "real" content of your files (once Git packs it later on) are simply smaller chunks known as `hunks` and Git knows how to index them into your original file.

---

### What are hunks?

Hunks are patch files. You can see them when you execute `git add -p` and then, if you have multiple changes on several locations in your files, choose the `s` and you will see them.

These are the options you can do within `add -p`:

```
y - stage this hunk
n - do not stage this hunk
q - quit, do not stage this hunk nor any of the remaining ones
a - stage this and all the remaining hunks in the file
d - do not stage this hunk nor any of the remaining hunks in the file
g - select a hunk to go to
/ - search for a hunk matching the given regex
j - leave this hunk undecided, see next undecided hunk
J - leave this hunk undecided, see next hunk
k - leave this hunk undecided, see previous undecided hunk
K - leave this hunk undecided, see the previous hunk
s - split the current hunk into smaller hunks
e - manually edit the current hunk
? - print help
```

Once you use the `s`, it will pick the chunk of code which can be considered as a standalone change. If you want to split it even more, you will have to use the `e` to edit the hunk and then add it back to the stage area.

---

Git stores "patches" which are the delta of your changes, but Git adds a few other "layers" on top of it. It **reuses** the same content once it "sees" it, (it's being done using the heuristics) and adding only "new" changes while pointing to the old ones.

Later on, Git grabs the content and packs it using ZIP.

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks. How can find these patch?

Comment: best way is to use `grepdiff 'console' --output-matching=....` read about this tool, if you are on windows it might be a problem

Comment: Hi, I have update the question to provide more info, do you have time to take a look. And I also tried the add -p, seems it only work when I made change to the same file, if  two file has similar content, it can't detect these change.

Comment: "if two file has similar content, it can't detect these change" of course, git re-use the same content and does not duplicate it even when you copy or rename file

Comment: Similar, a little different, but not the same. Sorry for not clear expression.

Comment: Git does *not* store "patches which are the delta of your changes". Instead, it uses both of "compressed versions of individual files" and "differences between similar files". These latter are not tied to changes made to files, but it often amounts to that.

Comment: @CodeWizard i have read that git store complete snapshots unlike centralized version control system like svn, now I m getting confused. is git storing delta or complete snapshot if file is modified?

Comment: It's more complicated than that, git store hunks, git "calculate" the differences, and that store the. Git search for code similarity based upon the Histogram algorithm, check for similarity of code based upon percentage, and more.

to make it short: git compares the code, creates a path (called hunk) and then stores those hunks as differences. Search for explanation oh how gt does its heuristics, as mentioned above it based upon number fo lines changes, percentage and more.