# Keep '.git' folder size low while tracking very big files

Tags: git

I am trying to set up a local Git for a 150 GB folder. I could finally make it work, but the *.git* folder in that repository also grew up to a bit over 100 GB, mostly from objects.

Most of the big files aren't going to change often, but I still wish to have them included in the repository.

I tried to rewrite history, but since there needs to be at least one commit adding those files, it seems they end up added to the objects folder no matter what.

Is there a way to reduce the *.git* folder when the tracked folder is pretty big itself?

PS: I do have *[git-lfs](https://git-lfs.github.com/)* installed, but it didn't seem to have an effect

Comment: Have you tell to git-lfs to trak your big files `git lfs track "*.huge"`

Comment: Related: *[Make Git consume less disk space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398919/)* and *[Reduce Git repository size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116778/reduce-git-repository-size/2116892#2116892)*

Answer (score 3):

Git maintains a local cache of files managed by LFS in the `.git/lfs/objects` folder. You can make it leaner with [git-lfs-prune](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/man/git-lfs-prune.1.ronn). If you are concerned about not having two copies of these large files on disk, you can use the [git-lfs-dedup](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/man/git-lfs-dedup.1.ronn) command so that the file in your Git workspace link to the cache instead of being copies. Disabling the local LFS cache is not supported yet. This request is tracked at https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/2147.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already committed the big files without Git LFS, then they exist as normal objects in your `.git` folder, i.e., including all their content. To fix this:

1. configure Git to store the large files using Git LFS: `git lfs track "*.gif"` (replace `.gif` with the extension of your large files)
2. rewrite or delete all Git history and recommit the files

Now the big files will be stored in Git LFS and not in your `.git` folder.

Comment: Like I said, LFS is already installed and I could verify that those big files are tracked by LFS. From what I understand LFS only reduce the size impact of future commits, doesn't seem to lower the size of adding the files

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying. I have added [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65296940/1363753) that addresses this case.